# Insert a file into specific directory/node using vfsStream

Tags: php, unit-testing, oop, phpunit, vfs-stream

The use case of [vfsStream](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream) is as follows:

```
$directories = explode('/', 'path/to/some/dir');

$structure = [];
$reference =& $structure;

foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    $reference[$directory] = [];
    $reference =& $reference[$directory];
}

vfsStream::setup();
$root = vfsStream::create($structure);
$file = vfsStream::newFile('file')
    ->at($root) //should changes be introduced here?
    ->setContent($content = 'Some content here');
```

The output of `vfsStream::inspect(new vfsStreamStructureVisitor())->getStructure()` is

```
Array
(
    [root] => Array
    (
        [path] => Array
        (
            [to] => Array
            (
                [some] => Array
                (
                    [dir] => Array
                    (
                    )
                )
            )
        )

        [file] => Some content here
    )
)
```

Is it possible to insert a file into specific directory, for example, under `dir` directory?

Comment: The simplest way of doing that, after reading the docs a bit, seems to actually build the file in the structure at the start. Why can't you define it when building the structure?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier yes, that could be possible; however I seek the solution for the given situation. Wonder if that could be achieved in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given [on github](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream/issues/127#issuecomment-169308533); thus instead of

```
->at($root)
```

one should use

```
->at($root->getChild('path/to/some/dir')).
```

Comment: This leads to following error at my end `TypeError: Argument 1 passed to org\bovigo\vfs\vfsStreamAbstractContent::at() must implement interface org\bovigo\vfs\vfsStreamContainer, instance of org\bovigo\vfs\vfsStreamFile given`
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, apparently it is possible to add a child to a `vfsStreamFirectory` with the [`addChild()`](http://vfs.bovigo.org/apidoc/classes/org.bovigo.vfs.vfsStreamDirectory.html#addChild) method:

However I've found no simple method in the [API Docs](http://vfs.bovigo.org/apidoc/packages/Default.html) that allow for easily traversing a structure to add content. Here is a horrible hacky of doing this *for this particular case*, it would fail if for instance there were more than one folder per path element.

Basically we have to recursively step through each level, verify if the name is the one to which we want to add the file, then add it when it's found.

```
use org\bovigo\vfs\vfsStream;
use org\bovigo\vfs\vfsStreamDirectory;
use org\bovigo\vfs\visitor\vfsStreamStructureVisitor;

$directories = explode('/', 'path/to/some/dir');

$structure = [];
$reference =& $structure;

foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    $reference[$directory] = [];
    $reference =& $reference[$directory];
}

vfsStream::setup();
$root = vfsStream::create($structure);
$file = vfsStream::newFile('file')
    ->setContent($content = 'Some content here');

$elem = $root;
while ($elem instanceof vfsStreamDirectory)
{
    if ($elem->getName() === 'dir')
    {
        $elem->addChild($file);
    }
    $children = $elem = $elem->getChildren();
    if (!isset($children[0]))
    {
        break;
    }
    $elem = $children[0];
}

print_r(vfsStream::inspect(new vfsStreamStructureVisitor())->getStructure());
```

Comment: Yeah, it feels a bit hacky but still does the job. One should raise a Github issue.